# Give class to dynamically created button in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, components, setattribute

I am creating a button and assigning class in component.ts. Style of css does not apply on the button (button font color doest not change). Code of component.ts is

```
let button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'North';
button.setAttribute('class', 'btn');

let element = document.createElement('div');
element.appendChild(button);
```

and component.css is

```
.btn
{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this `document.createElement('button')` if you're using Angular?

Comment: What's the alternate then?

Comment: The official tutorial gives a great intro to Angular https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Under what conditions are you adding the button? Is it a one-time thing, or do you have an array of them? What's your current HTML? What's your current component code?

Comment: I am trying to create it once my component is loaded ( in "ngOnInit()" fucntion). It is one time thing. Current html is empty as I want to show a single button only.

Comment: You mean like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fcq2tc

Comment: Yes. You are adding button in html. I want to do the same in component.ts.

Comment: But *why*? You should be interacting with the DOM as little as possible in Angular. You can always obtain a reference to the HTML element in the component if you really need it.

Comment: Right. Thanks for your help. I am trying to do as instructed by you.

Comment: why not add components that represent a button?

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
button.classList.add("btn");
```

Comment: This still won't work. component.css classes apply themselves via some component-specific attributes that Angular applies to the elements declared in the HTML file. By creating the button manually outside of Angular, the attribute won't be added, and no classes from component.css will be applied

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Use angular components for create buttons

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: '',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('element', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private _componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _injector: Injector,
  ) {}

  addButton(): void {
    const [componentRef, componentInstance] = this._createButton();
    componentInstance.title = 'North'
    componentInstance.class = 'active'

    this.container.insert(componentRef.hostView);
  }

  private _createButton(): [ComponentRef<ButtonComponent>, ButtonComponent] {
    const componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ButtonComponent);
    const componentRef = componentFactory.create(this._injector)

    const componentInstance = componentRef.instance;

    return [componentRef ,componentInstance];
  }
}
```

button component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.css'],
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() class: string = '';
}
```

I put the whole example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xiw47p)